# How to get Firebase Authentication Created Date

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

How to get these details:

[image: these details]

I have tried to get this by following method

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
long joineDate = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp();
String joined_on_date = String.valueOf(joineDate);
joined_on.setText(joined_on_date);
```

But that looks like this:

[image: like this]

So how to display it in date format

No the question linked doesent answer my question when I get those date from firebase it shows some random numbers which I dont know in which form it is.

Comment: The "random numbers" are actually the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970, commonly referred to as epoch time. If you pass it into `new Date` (as the accepted answer in the question Zoe linked), then you'll have a standard date.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try my best!